# How to Dump, Load and Read info from pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I am creating some code that asks a user some questions and stores their data in a list. I want to be able to save that list and store it so when they come back, they can pick up right where they left off. It's a simple program so I'm not trying to make it super complicated. Can I use pickle to accomplish this?

```
import pickle

username = raw_input("Choose a username \n")
password = raw_input("Choose a password \n")
username_password = {}

def save_progress(save):

if 'yes' in save:
    username_password[username] = password

    with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
            pickle.dump(like_people, handle) #like_people is a list with data
            pickle.dump(username_password, handle)
    return "Progress saved"

elif 'no' in save:
    print "Alright we won't save your progress"

else:
    print "I don't know what happened"

print save_progress(raw_input("Would you like to save your progress \n").lower())
```

If I wanted to create a function

```
def load_progress(load):
    if 'yes' in load:
        #have them input their username
        #have them input their password
        #How would I check to see if that username + password matched what they originally
        #inputted and if so, load their progress
    elif 'no' in load:
        return "Alright we won't be loading"
    else:
        print "I don't know what is happening"
```

Can I even use pickle to accomplish this? If I need to edit or add anything, just let me know and I will.

Comment: Yes you certainly can, just what data do you need to recreate the state of the program upon restart? Just have a file, dump these data to that file every time the program is shut down, read from it after restart and re-create the state from before the shutdown.

Comment: I just need the like_people list that was dumped so I can add onto it. Everything else is already in place

Comment: OK so the question really is how to detect whether the program is being shutdown or started up anew, am I right? If so you way want to look at WX as it gives you tools to control the lifecycle of your program. Specifically you may be interested in this (not sure if this is the thing, but something similar certainly is) http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_close_event.html . WX are also available with Python bindings and are super easy to learn: http://www.wxpython.org/ I prefer WX but there are many alternatives to choose from

Comment: Yes you are correct! Thank you so much for the resources I will definitely be using them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as pickle is concerned, the answer is:

```
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as infile:
    loaded_people = pickle.load(infile)
    loaded_user = pickle.load(infile)
#have them input their username
#have them input their password
if username_password.get(username) == password:
    print 'OK, loaded'
    like_people = loaded_data
    username_password = loaded_user
else:
    raise Exception('nice try but no cigar')
```

However, from a security point of view saving the password like that was dubious to begin with.

If the user can read the file, they can see the username and password for themselves, and type that in when they run your program. Since users (despite being told not to) typically use the same password for different things, it's anti-social to risk leaking a password even if you don't actually care about the security of the thing *you're* protecting.

The fix for that is nothing really to do with pickle files, look up password hashing and/or signing with HMAC. If you also want to keep the data itself secret from someone who can read the file but doesn't know the password, you need encryption.

Alternatively, if you don't need any security at all, just a name to associate with this stored data, then drop the "password" entirely. There's no point making something look like a login if it isn't one really.

Comment: Good points. I will drop the password, it is unnecessary for the purpose of this program. Thanks for the suggestion!